# Import CSV file into MySQL server in DBeaver

Tags: sql, csv, dbeaver

I connected my AWS MySql Server to Dbeaver and want to import a csv file into my AWS database. I go through the 'import data' wizard, but only the header row appears. I mirror this process with the SQLite sample database and it works great. Any clue why I can't get this to work on MySQL databases?